# Quiz app. Problem with output of random answers

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to make my first quiz app. The application displays the first question and answers in random order. The first question works correctly. When you click the Next button, the second question appears, but the answers do not change. Maybe a problem with List<String> answers = []; I can't decide without your help.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:australia/qlist';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  List<Color> colorsList = [
    Colors.white,
    Colors.white,
    Colors.white,
    Colors.white
  ];

  List<String> answers = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    answers.addAll([
      QuestionsList.shared.getCurrentQuestion().correctAnswer,
      QuestionsList.shared.getCurrentQuestion().dis1,
      QuestionsList.shared.getCurrentQuestion().dis2,
      QuestionsList.shared.getCurrentQuestion().dis3,
    ]);
    answers.shuffle();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: Column(children: [
          Center(
              child: Text(QuestionsList.shared.getCurrentQuestion().question)),
          Card(
            color: colorsList[0],
            child: InkWell(
              child: Text(answers[0]),
              onTap: () {
                if (answers[0] ==
                    QuestionsList.shared.getCurrentQuestion().correctAnswer) {
                  colorsList[0] = Colors.green;
                  setState(() {});
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
          Card(
            color: colorsList[1],
            child: InkWell(
              child: Text(answers[1]),
              onTap: () {
                if (answers[1] ==
                    QuestionsList.shared.getCurrentQuestion().correctAnswer) {
                  colorsList[1] = Colors.green;
                  setState(() {});
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
          Card(
            color: colorsList[2],
            child: InkWell(
              child: Text(answers[2]),
              onTap: () {
                if (answers[2] ==
                    QuestionsList.shared.getCurrentQuestion().correctAnswer) {
                  colorsList[2] = Colors.green;
                  setState(() {});
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
          Card(
            color: colorsList[3],
            child: InkWell(
              child: Text(answers[3]),
              onTap: () {
                if (answers[3] ==
                    QuestionsList.shared.getCurrentQuestion().correctAnswer) {
                  colorsList[3] = Colors.green;
                  setState(() {});
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                QuestionsList.shared.nextQuestion();
                setState(() {});
              },
              child: Text('NEXT'))
        ]));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check my onTap() code of next click, i think that code useful you to achieve your functionality.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:australia/qlist';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  List<Color> colorsList = [
    Colors.white,
    Colors.white,
    Colors.white,
    Colors.white
  ];

  List<String> answers = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    answers.addAll([
      QuestionsList.shared.getCurrentQuestion().correctAnswer,
      QuestionsList.shared.getCurrentQuestion().dis1,
      QuestionsList.shared.getCurrentQuestion().dis2,
      QuestionsList.shared.getCurrentQuestion().dis3,
    ]);
    answers.shuffle();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: Column(children: [
          Center(
              child: Text(QuestionsList.shared.getCurrentQuestion().question)),
          Card(
            color: colorsList[0],
            child: InkWell(
              child: Text(answers[0]),
              onTap: () {
                if (answers[0] ==
                    QuestionsList.shared.getCurrentQuestion().correctAnswer) {
                  colorsList[0] = Colors.green;
                  setState(() {});
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
          Card(
            color: colorsList[1],
            child: InkWell(
              child: Text(answers[1]),
              onTap: () {
                if (answers[1] ==
                    QuestionsList.shared.getCurrentQuestion().correctAnswer) {
                  colorsList[1] = Colors.green;
                  setState(() {});
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
          Card(
            color: colorsList[2],
            child: InkWell(
              child: Text(answers[2]),
              onTap: () {
                if (answers[2] ==
                    QuestionsList.shared.getCurrentQuestion().correctAnswer) {
                  colorsList[2] = Colors.green;
                  setState(() {});
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
          Card(
            color: colorsList[3],
            child: InkWell(
              child: Text(answers[3]),
              onTap: () {
                if (answers[3] ==
                    QuestionsList.shared.getCurrentQuestion().correctAnswer) {
                  colorsList[3] = Colors.green;
                  setState(() {});
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                QuestionsList.shared.nextQuestion();
                answers.clear();
                answers.addAll([
                    QuestionsList.shared.getCurrentQuestion().correctAnswer,
                    QuestionsList.shared.getCurrentQuestion().dis1,
                    QuestionsList.shared.getCurrentQuestion().dis2,
                    QuestionsList.shared.getCurrentQuestion().dis3,
                ]);
                answers.shuffle();
                setState(() {});
              },
              child: Text('NEXT'))
        ]));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Now everything works correctly.